# Replacing variable entries to be the same in each group

Tags: stata

I'm working with panel data in Stata, and I have a set up like the following:

| ID | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 |  |
| 1 | 2011 | 20 |
| 1 | 2012 | 20 |
| 1 | 2013 |  |
| 1 | 2014 |  |
| 2 | 2010 |  |
| 2 | 2011 | 14 |
| 2 | 2012 | 14 |
| 2 | 2013 | 14 |
| 2 | 2014 | 14 |

and I want to change the blank entries to be the same as the other entries within that ID, for any year. I.e., I want something like the following:

| ID | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 20 |
| 1 | 2011 | 20 |
| 1 | 2012 | 20 |
| 1 | 2013 | 20 |
| 1 | 2014 | 20 |
| 2 | 2010 | 14 |
| 2 | 2011 | 14 |
| 2 | 2012 | 14 |
| 2 | 2013 | 14 |
| 2 | 2014 | 14 |

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value in variable `value` are always the same within `id` you can use this:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id int year byte value
1 2010  .
1 2011 20
1 2012 20
1 2013  .
1 2014  .
2 2010  .
2 2011 14
2 2012 14
2 2013 14
2 2014 14
end

*Get mean of values within id
bysort id : egen value2 = mean(value) 

*Transfer values back to original var to maintain var labels etc. then drop value2
replace value = value2
drop value2
```

Comment: Cautious even paranoid code might include a check that at most one non-missing value was given for each identifier. One check is to look for the minimum and maximum and check that they are equal.  See https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1648656-replace-variable-values-with-first-meaningful-value-in-panel-study for an example.